# Compile time in .Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am developing a web application. When I build the application I can see the statement "Build Succeeded" in status bar even the syntax of object declaration is wrong in a aspx.cs file. I cleaned the solution again I tried to rebuild the application. But I did not get any error. If I am adding any block of code in that page it is not executing in run time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Web Site Project or Web Application Project?
I've had to work on a Web Site Project where you'd only get compiler errors at runtime because of the way Web Site Projects handle compilation of code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to assess the exact situation without seeing the structure in the Visual Studio solution. Can you verify that the .aspx page you are working on has its Page directive tag pointing to the correct .aspx.cs code-behind file you are modifying?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="I_AM_MODIFYING_THIS_PAGE.aspx.cs" Inherits="I_AM_MODIFYING_THIS_PAGE" %>
```